# How to show last facebook posts from default user as XML output

Tags: xml, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have created a ASP.NET page that's using Facebook API. I can read last Facebook posts from the default user. The situation is as follows:

1. Open ASP.NET page
2. Enter the username, which you want to see the posts.
3. If you are logged in to Facebook, there will be access_token generated for you, otherwise you will be redirected to Facebook authorization window.
4. You must accept the application.
5. The application sends request to Graph API. The results are JSON output.

Is there any possibility to see posts from the default user, without authorization steps?

How can I get the results as XML output?

Can I read XML Feed from Facebook posts?

Comment: No - you can't get the results in XML. Facebook only returns JSON data. You'll have to find a JSON -> XML converter or write one that meets your needs.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the posts by the default user? You mean the user that actually logged in?

Comment: I enter the username, which I want to see results. You just log in with your Facebook account but you get the results from your friend for example.

Comment: You just specify the users Facebook ID.. I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're asking...

Comment: Yes that's what i'm doing at this moment, I'm using the users Facebook ID to get their Facebook posts.

Comment: I found a solution! To get around the authorization you have just to create an access_token with a base of your app_id and app_secret.

Answer (score 0):

Or much easier way, find out you facebook unique ID on here: http://findmyfacebookid.com/
then type this into the browser: https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id={0}&format=rss20
However replace the {0} with the ID you got from findmyfacebookid